# sense what screen size and adjust the column widths with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

im using 960 and i want to adjust the nr of columns depending on the user's screen size.

how do javascript/jquery get the resolution of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`screen.width` will tell you the screens width. Or maybe `screen.availWidth` would be better. Note also that with jQuery you can get the `$.width()` and `$.height()` of items: `$(window).width()` for instance will tell you how wide your window is.

Comment: what is the difference between width and availwidth?

Comment: `availWidth` excludes scrollbars, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that screen size doesn't matter. What matters is how wide their viewport for your page is. They could have a 3000px across screen, but be viewing your page with only 1000px wide browser window.

In jQuery you can get the viewport width like this:

```
 $(window).width()
```

Comment: +1 Indeed. A very good point. I too think he is asking the wrong question.